# Videojs multiple url as source

Tags: javascript, flash, video.js

I need to implement videjs in javascript and I have the below-mentioned code.

```
     var rtmpURL ="rtmp://xyz.xyz";
     var httpURL ="http://xyz.xyz";
     var video = videojs('player', { techOrder: ['flash', 'html5'] });
     video.src({src:srcURL, type: 'rtmp/mp4'});
     video.play();
```

How can I give RTMP as well as HTTP urls as source?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array of source objects:

```
video.src([
  {src: rtmpURL, type: 'rtmp/mp4'},
  {src: httpURL, type: 'video/mp4'}
]);
```

Comment: still player trying to load http URL first.